# Possible for Views to format a table with multiple rows as needed?

Tags: views

What I have is a basic content format of item, index, description

```
+----------+---------------------+
|  index   |  item               |
+----------+---------------------+
|  description                   |
|                                |
+--------------------------------+
```

The Content type: Manage field *wizard* has an option to allow multiple instances of a field in a node. It's a real help for my content. Now, I wish to create a View to display this content in a table (Views: Fields: Table: Settings), that will add rows to the basic form above as needed (according to the node's field limitations)

```
+----------+---------------------+
|  index   |  item               |
+----------+---------------------+
|  description                   |
|                                |
+----------+---------------------+
|  index   |  related item       |
+----------+---------------------+
|  index   |  related item       |
+----------+---------------------+
|  ...     |  ...                |
+----------+---------------------+
```

<strike>* (I'm using a table because I'm also using Draggableviews)</strike>

I've found Views Secondary Row Module, yet the idea is to accommodate any number of related items.

Any suggestions?

---

Its not particularly necessary to use table, now that I think of it, because the draggable view admin page doesn't *need* to be well formatted. The content does seem to want to be an a table, as I've described, but its *not necessary*.

Comment: So the content type has a field which can have more multiple entries? If not, could you describe your content type a bit better and which field / data you would like to display?

Comment: Yes. As you can see in the illustration, the base node has the three fields required for the content type (item, index, description). There are two optional fields (index, related item). For the purpose of the question, assume the content is some kind of inventory and it necessary to display the index value so avoiding the easy fix of an Entity Reference. (^_^) Does that help?

Comment: More specifically the wizard section is, [field name] Field settings: Number of values

Comment: In views, you can set the field to show each value in a separate row instead of showing them all in one. But i think this is not what you're looking for?

Comment: I try not to 'go discussion' on stack, prefering to just answer the question. Yet your suggestion views could make a table of row headers instead of columns is different. Your're not referring to a list, yes?  If true, it is certainly a useful discussion! Im looking at Semanticviews but have not yet discovered if it will create tables...